# Cannot get image

Tags: python

Why does the code below that I got from here:

http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/image-classification-in-Python.html

Give no result. Everything seems to be Ok. It runs without error, but I get no images.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import os


def get_soup(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

image_type = "check"
query = "check"
url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + query + \ 
    "&qft=+filterui:color2-bw+filterui:imagesize-large&FORM=R5IR3"

soup = get_soup(url)
images = [a['src'] for a in soup.find_all("img", {"src": re.compile("mm.bing.net")})]

for img in images:
    raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(img).read()
    cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir("images") if image_type in i]) + 1
    f = open("images/" + image_type + "_"+ str(cntr), 'wb')
    f.write(raw_img)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Try printing `images` before entering the loop. It might just be empty.

Comment: It is empty. That is my problem. The soup object and the bing result page are not empty. Thanks for the quick response though

Comment: what is the a['src'] doing?

Comment: Shouldn't `re.compile("mm.bing.net")` be `re.compile(".*mm.bing.net.*")`

Comment: @ a['src']: I was also wondering about that. But maybe it some kind of index. But I really don't know. @hkpeprah: I just tried that and got no error, but no images. Just like before.

Answer (score 0):

I got a `SyntaxError` and changed the `url` line to:

```
url = ("http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + query +
       "&qft=+filterui:color2-bw+filterui:imagesize-large&FORM=R5IR3")
```

Then it just ran fine.

Comment: Thanks. But not for me. I tried that already in all variations.

Answer (score 0):

The attr "src" should be "src2". Try this code.

```
images = [a['src2'] for a in soup.find_all("img", {"src2": re.compile("mm.bing.net")})]
```